# Using custom datum for `mustPayToOtherScript` in off-chain code

Tags: plutus, datum, offchain, builtindata

Lets say I on-chain i have a Datum like so:

```
data RandomDatum = RandomDatum {
   { tn :: !TokenName
   , cs :: !CurrencySymbol
   , nn :: !Integer
   } deriving (Show)
```

Off chain I'm trying to form and submit transaction with:

```
...
let dat = RandomDatum { 
       tn = ""
     , cs = ""
     , nn = 1
    }
    constraints = Constraints.mustPayToOtherScript vh dat val

ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraintsWith lookups constraints
```

But my compilation always fails, because `dat` is not of type `Datum`.
I have also tried:

```
constraints = Constraints.mustPayToOtherScript vh (Datum $ PlutusTx.toBuiltinData dat) val
```

## Question

How could I convert `RandomDatum` imported from my `on-chain` code file?

Comment: I dig more into this and now I think it doesn't work because `PlutusTx.unstableMakeIsData`fails to generate required instances for `FromData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I didn't provide correct type to `submitTxConstraintsWith` call.

If this was code from Plutus Pioneer Program week one where there is a definition:

```
data Auctioning
instance Scripts.ValidatorTypes Auctioning where
    type instance RedeemerType Auctioning = AuctionAction
    type instance DatumType Auctioning = AuctionDatum
```

Call should look like this:

```
ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraintsWith @Auctioning lookups constraints
```

Also datum needs `deriving (Show, Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)` for serialization

```
data RandomDatum = RandomDatum {
   { tn :: !TokenName
   , cs :: !CurrencySymbol
   , nn :: !Integer
   } deriving (Show, Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know your datum types are required to conform the Data type.
Try:

```
PlutusTx.makeIsDataIndexed ''RandomDatum [ ('RandomDatum, 0) ]

{...}
let randomDatum = RandomDatum { ...params... }
    tx          = mustPayToTheScript randomDatum $ Ada.lovelaceValueOf amount
{...}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some Haskell Language pragma which is required for this? What pragrams are required for this? I do have `PlutusTx.makeIsDataIndexed` in separate `on-chain` code file but I still get this error.

Comment: @KugisMugis In that case, can you post complete on chain and off chain code?